# Is there an issue with FileReader or BufferedReader in Java 8?

Tags: java, eclipse, bufferedreader, filereader

```
package fbread;

import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.io.FileReader;  
import java.io.IOException;

public class Read {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("text.txt");

    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        br.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found: " + file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to read file: " + file);
    }

}

}
```

So I've got this code in Eclipse, in my opinion is 100% correct, however, when I run it, an error pops up in Eclipse (grey square, red cross, no message) and nothing shows up in the console.

Anyone got any idea why is this happening ?

I've also attached the image with the error below:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiZnR.png)

Comment: I think that your Eclipse is "tired". Try to restart it and check you don't have configuration project issue in the "Problems" tab.

Comment: That dialog doesn't seem to have anything to do with your program. Looks like a bugged IDE, or just something else random on your computer.

Comment: It's not the issue, but: Definitely not 100% correct. You never close the `FileReader` if there's an error constructing the `BufferedReader`. There almost certainly won't be an error constructing the `BufferedReader`, but the pattern is still wrong. Instead, use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Comment: After reinstalling Eclipse it's working, don't know exactly what the issue was. thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

I just run your code, and i had no errors. I am using eclipse Luna. the only changes that i made is that i wrapped the class in a package with a different name, plus i used an absolute path to define the file to be opened. It's very possible that something went wrong with your IDE during runtime, but setting files using absolute directories is always a good idea.

Hope this helps! I am attaching the code...

`package soproblem;

import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.io.FileReader;  
import java.io.IOException;

public class Read {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\file.txt");

    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        br.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found: " + file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to read file: " + file);
    }

   }

 }`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no there isn't a problem with `FileReader` or `BufferedReader` in Java 8.

The problem ... apparently ... was that your IDE was in a strange state that was cured by a restart.

---

For other people who think that they might have encountered a problem in some common Java SE class, the chances are greater than 99.99% that the problem in not in Java.  It is far more likely that the real problem is one of the following:

- A bug in your code due to carelessness, inexperience, misunderstanding some class / method you are using, making incorrect assumptions, and so on.
- A bug in a 3rd party language.
- An IDE misbehaving (if you are running your code in an IDE).  (Try running your app from the command line.)
- A damaged Java or IDE installation.

Yes, new bugs are found ... very occasionally ... in the JVM and Java SE libraries.  But this is so rare that this should be considering all other possibilities first.  'Cos an *"its a Java bug!"* misdiagnosis is going to stop looking for the real cause of your problem.

Remember, there a millions of other programmers using Java SE without experiencing these "bugs".  Java 8 which was released 6 years ago.  That is long enough for all but the most obscure of bugs to have been found and fixed already.

Answer (score -1):

YOU CAN SIMPLIFY YOUR CODE WITH :

```
package BufferedReader;
import java.io.*;

public class Buffered {

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\filename.txt"));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    br.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: Yea ... great.  Now instead of outputing an error message, the code throws a stacktrace in the user's face.